# C++ qsort algorithm for C#?

Tags: c#, qsort

I'm trying to port over some of my old C/C++ code to C#/Unity. In several places, I called the qsort function. Here's an example:

```
qsort((void *) CardSort, NumCards, sizeof (CardSort[0]), SortFunction);
```

where SortFunction is a pointer to my own criterion function. Here is one example:

```
int SortFunction (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   int i, j, iValue, jValue;
   memcpy (&i, a, 2);
   memcpy (&j, b, 2);
   iValue = TrickValue (i, GetSuit (i));
   jValue = TrickValue (j, GetSuit (j));
   return (iValue - jValue);
}
```

This is only one example of several I need to import. I've tried to replicate this using a quicksort algorithm (pivot, left, right), but I need to modify every instance of it to reflect my different SortFunctions. Each one is kind of a pain.

I would like to just write my own qsort routine so I can simply pull in my code unchanged, but I can't find an example online. Since I have no insight into the inner workings of the original qsort, I'm hoping someone here can assist me.

In short: Is there a C# implementation, or can someone guide me into writing my own, that duplicates the functionality of C/C++ qsort?

Comment: The `Array.Sort` method uses Quicksort most of the time.  See [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Collections_IComparer_).

Comment: The SortFunction is an implementation of IComparer<T>, and you can use it in several functions like Array.Sort, List.Sort,  Linq.Orderby, etc. There is not really a point to care for the Sort Algorithm yourself. If you want higher-performance, keep it in C. There is also Managed C++, that is a C++ for .NET, but this is declared deprecated know. So don't keep your code. Keep your ideas.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against re-implementing your own sort and then porting line-for-line your comparison algorithms.  C# already has mechanisms for sorting in-place, sorting externally, sorting with a comparison key, sorting with a comparator object, and so on; we have a rich, fully-featured, world-class library of sequence manipulation functions. **Learn how to use them**. That will save you time in the long run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qsort is a QuickSort implementation, AFAIK `Array.Sort()` in C# is a QuickSort implementation. There are several overloads but I think you are looking for the one that takes a keys array and the values array.

Comment: So, would I call 
    Array.Sort (CardSort, NumCards, Length, new SortFunction);

and SortFunction would be written as:

    public class SortFunction : IComparer  
    {
      int IComparer.Compare(Object x, Object y)  
      {
          int i, j, iValue, jValue;
          memcpy (&i, a, 2);  <= I realize I'd have to change these
          memcpy (&j, b, 2);
          iValue = TrickValue (i, GetSuit (i));
          jValue = TrickValue (j, GetSuit (j));
          return (iValue - jValue);
        }
    }

Is that the right idea? (Sorry, I can't get the code to format.)

Comment: What are your keys?

Comment: Okay, I got it working. Thanks so much for putting me on to the Array overloads. I had seen some examples, but none that used the IComparer overloads.